# sa authentication error, but can log into sql server management studio with sa account

Tags: java, sql-server, jackrabbit, primavera

Server running Primavera Contract Management which uses jboss5.0.1.GA. users are getting an error message "content repository not initialized" when try to make changes to submittal logs. if edit or create a submittal, changes are successful even though receive the error. however, cannot delete items as receive same error message, but items do not delete. in looking in the logs for jboss and sql, i see an authentication failure for "sa" but i can log into sql server manager with the sa account and the password.

SQL log:

```
Starting up database 'EXPADMIN'.
2019-01-20 08:54:06.31 spid59      Starting up database 'CMDEMO'.
2019-01-20 08:54:06.84 spid64      Starting up database 'PROJECTS'.
2019-01-20 08:54:07.17 spid69      Starting up database 'expflb2'.
2019-01-20 08:54:14.69 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-01-20 08:54:14.69 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.1.5]
```

JBOSS log:

```
ERROR [org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem] (main) failed to initialize file system
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

Not sure why i am getting these errors when i can log into SQL server manager withe the sa account. any help is greatly appreciated as we do not have support on the old Primavera software.

Comment: How have you verified that the passwords you're using are all the same?

Comment: Why are your users trying to log in with `sa` in the first place? They should have their own login and users (or the application should). Giving everyone `sa` access is a huge security flaw and you need to fix it ASAP.

Comment: For the "sa" account, i have logged into SQL server manager using the "sa" account. i dont know of any way to check from the jboss side. the "sa" account pw was changed but even reverting it back to the old pw, still get the same error.

Comment: users do have their own login to the primavera application, but the sa account is used to make the database connection.

Comment: when i look in SQL for users, the users created within the primavera software, which is a web page, do not show. i am guessing they are stored somewhere in the primavera software somewhere. i would like to know as there are a lot of old accounts in the software, but in the admin center, there is no way to remove them. the primavera is old software, version 13.1, which users java 6.20. the content repository uses jackrabbit.

Comment: The point that @Larnu is making is that NO application should be connecting using sa, period. You should create a primavera user and connect with that.

Comment: I think perhaps you are confused about users. Your software creates users and stores them in a sql table. This is NOT the same as a sql user.

Comment: i understand the difference about the users. This software was setup long before i came onboard, but i am the only IT person. the jackrabbit content repository connects using a different account named exp. i can connect with that account. the only error i am seeing in the logs is the "sa" account authentication failure which the logs shows does not allow the content repository to initalize.

Comment: My best guess is you have some connection string somewhere that has the wrong password for sa. I can't help you find it because until about 30 seconds ago I had no idea what a jackrabbit repository is. Perhaps you should add more tags relevant to the technology you are working with to attract a wider audience of people.

Comment: thanks. i had tried adding the tags but they werent in the list to select from. will keep digging to see what i can figure out.

Comment: Not really sure what tags are appropriate but they were pretty simple to find. Just start typing in the tags box and they pop right up.

Comment: already have all the tags except for jboss. when try to select the one for version 5 it says cannot create as need a 1500 score or something.  thanks for your help.